# trigger iframe onload event when doing an ajax replacement on content within the iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iframe, jquery, ajax.beginform

I have a view with a credit card payment form hosted on Domain A.  Domain B has a seperate website with an iframe to the credit card form on domain A.

The form on domain A uses an ajax form like this:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreditCard", "Framed", new { id = Model.SID },
   new AjaxOptions()
   {
       HttpMethod = "POST",
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
       UpdateTargetId = "credit-card-wrapper",
       LoadingElementId = "loading-pane"
   }, 
   new { id = "new-creditcard-form" }))
{ %>
```

Then on domain b, I am using a custom jquery plugin to manage my iframe by allowing external events to change the src of the iframe.  The usage looks like this

```
$('#myIframe').frameplugin('creditcard');
```

Which causes the iframe to change it's src to the credit card page.  I also have attached an onload to the iframe like this:

```
$(this).bind('load', function () {
    var src = $(this).attr('src').toLowerCase();

    //do stuff based on url
});
```

What I want to do is when the credit card form is submitted and the replacement is done, I want the document within the iframe to trigger the iframe's onload event, so that domain b knows something happened.

Another solution would be to somehow bind custom events to the iframe and trigger them within the framed document.  I'm not sure how/if that would even work.  Any ideas?

EDIT:

I am attempting to use an event trigger from the iframe up to the parent and I get an error.

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access
>   frame with URL
>   http://localhost:59905/Home/Framed
>   from frame with URL
>   http://localhost:27412/Framed/Index/.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must
>   match.

Here's my event binding

```
$(document).bind('success:myframe', function (event, referenceId) {
    //do something
});
```

and here's the javascript call from the framed page.  This is called from OnSuccess in the ajax.beginform

```
function paymentReceived() {
    var referenceNumber = $('#referenceNumber').text();
    $(top.document).trigger('success:myframe', referenceNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want to pass events from iFrame to the parent window.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

From your iFrame, can't you just do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    parent.alertPageWithIFrameThatLoadIsComplete();
});
```

Edit:
Let me try again.

This works for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function oniframeLoad() {
     alert("Loaded!");
    }

    function changePage() {
     frames["my_iframe"].location.href = "http://google.com";
    }

    setTimeout(changePage, 2000);
</script>

<iframe onload="oniframeLoad()" name="my_iframe" id="my_iframe" src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: I tried using trigger on the parent from within the iframe, but I get `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://localhost:59905/Home/Framed from frame with URL http://localhost:27412/Framed/Index/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

Comment: That cross-domain issue is real annoying.  Search for 'cross-domain hack' for information on how to get around it if you like.  I've updated the answer with another solution.

Comment: The onload event isn't fired when using ajax.  I have the onload event wired up.  My problem is I want to be able to pass specific custom events up from the iframe to the parent page.

Comment: This is a security risk, which is why it's generally not allowed.  You can use a cross-domain hack to achieve this.  See http://shouldersofgiants.co.uk/Blog/post/2009/08/17/Another-Cross-Domain-iFrame-Communication-Technique.aspx for an example.  (Click the ParentPage.html link).